# Objective C - Split array in multiple languagues

Tags: objective-c, multiple-languages, cjk

I have a string in multiple languagues like this @"America の りょこう".
How can I split it into array only contains simple word (included space) like this
[@"America", @" ", @"の", @" ", @"りょ", @"こ", @"う"

Comment: Is `componentsSeparatedByString:` not helpful in this case?

Comment: You can't do it